# vs2010 chart. How to group Y axis value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a bar chart. My X-axis are Names and my Y axis are age values. The default bar chart is set to intervals but I want a range (a yes and no chart). I want to make a Y axis displaying something like "under 13", "13-21","+21" and graphing it correctly. How do I do that? I been researching this for a while.

I just need to learn how to do this. But my  real project is similar.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us an example (possibly visual) of what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: You should probably add what type of chart control you are using (i.e what library).

Comment: Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart . BarGraph